# *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" not showing links

Tags: angular

**View**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-    toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MEAN Auth App</a>
     </div>
     <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] =  "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</a></li>

        <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}"><a [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()"><a (click)="onLogoutClick()" href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router,
    private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLogoutClick(){
    this.authService.logout();
    this.flashMessage.show('You are logged out', {
      cssClass:'alert-success',
      timeout: 3000
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

}
```

I'm new to the mean stack, and I'm having a problem with angular *ngIf, it removes the link from the navbar but doesn't put it back, it does not toggle when you log in or out. However, the ! does remove them, but permanently.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
forgot to add this

auth.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile () {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile',{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken () {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loggedIn () {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you expect us to reproduce your issue when there are multiple sections of your logic missing?

Comment: Can you show the authService.loggedIn() code

Comment: @AbhishekSingh loggedIn () {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

Comment: @AndrewWaller, you'll have to provide logic for the logout method as well. I'm sensing that this is due to JavaScript's nature of passing primitives by value and not by reference.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera i just edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the id_token from your local storage to `tokenNotExpired()` for it to actually check what token is not expired.

so your `loggedIn()` function should read likes this:

```
  loggedIn () {
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }
```